# why can't I use scrollToEnd or similar functions in my Jetpack Compose project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I 'm trying to go lazycolumn last item because I have a lazycolumn and empty list. The application I made is a chatbot application, there are bot messages and user messages. When the bot gives a message, it is added to the `list`, at the same time, when the user enters a reply, it is added to the `list` and as it is added to this `list`, the empty list starts to fill up and lazycolumn is also displayed, but it is a separate thing that should be in a correspondence application. As messages are added, that is, when the end of the screen is reached, the screen needs to slide down. I used `scrollToEnd` or something similar to do this, but my project does not see `scrollToEnd` and gives the following error `Unresolved reference: scrollToEnd` or for example `isScrolledToEnd()` When I use this, I wonder if there is a separate item that I should add. Is there a dependency or are they obsolete? can you help me solve this issue

---

```
var index = 1

@SuppressLint("CoroutineCreationDuringComposition")
@Composable
fun FirstScreen() {

    val list = remember { mutableStateListOf<Message>() }
    val UserList = remember { mutableStateListOf<Message>() }
    val botList = listOf("Peter", "Francesca", "Luigi", "Igor")
    val random = (0..3).random()
    val botName: String = botList[random]
    val hashMap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap<String, String>()
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    customBotMessage(message = Message1, list)

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.diyetkolik_logo),
            contentDescription = "logo",
            modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)
        )

        Divider()
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            state = listState) {
            println("size:"+list.size)
            items(list.size) { i ->

                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    horizontalArrangement =
                    if (list[i].id == RECEIVE_ID)
                        Arrangement.Start
                    else
                        Arrangement.End
                ) {
                    if (list[i].id == RECEIVE_ID) {
                        Item(
                            message = list[i],
                            botName,
                            botcolor,
                            list,
                            simpleTextFlag = true,
                            hashMap,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(
                                    start = 32.dp,
                                    end = 4.dp,
                                    top = 4.dp
                                ),
                        )
                    } else {
                        Item(
                            message = list[i],
                            "user",
                            usercolor,
                            UserList,
                            simpleTextFlag = false,
                            hashMap,
                            Modifier.padding(
                                start = 4.dp,
                                end = 32.dp,
                                top = 4.dp
                            )
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        val endOfListReached = remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                listState.isAtBottom() // error occurs @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
            }
        }

        // act when end of list reached
        LaunchedEffect(endOfListReached) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}

private fun customBotMessage(message: String, list: SnapshotStateList<Message>) {

    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            list.add(
                Message(
                    message,
                    RECEIVE_ID,
                    Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()
                )
            )

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
@Composable
fun Item(
    message: Message,
    person: String,
    color: Color,
    list: SnapshotStateList<Message>,
    simpleTextFlag: Boolean,
    hashMap: HashMap<String, String>,
    modifier: Modifier
) {

    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(10.dp),
            backgroundColor = color,
            elevation = 10.dp
        ) {
            Row(
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(3.dp)
            ) {
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(
                            style = SpanStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                                color = Color.Black
                            )
                        ) {
                            append("$person: ")
                        }
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(4.dp)
                )
                Text(
                    buildAnnotatedString {
                        withStyle(
                            style = SpanStyle(
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.W900,
                                color = Color.White//Color(/*0xFF4552B8*/)
                            )
                        )
                        {
                            append(message.message)
                        }
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        if (simpleTextFlag)
            SimpleText(list = list, hashMap)
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class, ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SimpleText(list: SnapshotStateList<Message>, hashMap: HashMap<String, String>) {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        visible = visible,
        enter = fadeIn() + slideInHorizontally(),
        exit = fadeOut() + slideOutHorizontally()
    ) {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.Bottom,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End,
            modifier = Modifier.bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(2.dp)
                    .onFocusEvent { focusState ->
                        if (focusState.isFocused) {
                            coroutineScope.launch {
                                bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                            }
                        }
                    },
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = { keyboardController?.hide() }),
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { text = it },
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                label = { Text("send message") })
            IconButton(onClick = {
                if (text.isNotEmpty()) {
                    //Adds it to our local list
                    list.add(
                        Message(
                            text,
                            Constants.SEND_ID,
                            Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()
                        )
                    )
                    hashMap.put(Messages.listOfMessageKeys[index - 1], text)
                    customBotMessage(listOfMessages[index], list)
                    index += 1
                    visible = false
                }
                text = ""


            }) {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(2.dp),
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_baseline_send_24),
                    contentDescription = "send message img"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun customBotMessage(message: String, list: SnapshotStateList<Message>) {

    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(1000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            list.add(
                Message(
                    message,
                    Constants.RECEIVE_ID,
                    Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString()
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's badly written code and you might have trouble understanding it, so I'll explain how the code works for you. Briefly, the first screen that opens is FirstScreen and there is an empty list that I defined here, and by empty list I mean `val list = remember { mutableStateListOf<Message>() }` in FirstScreen. First, I call the `customBotMessage` function to interact with the user, and it adds the first message in the message list I prepared. When added to the `list`, it enters the lazycolumn and is displayed on the screen as an `Item`.

When going to `Item`, there is a message box in the `Item` and a textfield just below the message box where the user can enter an input, if the message incoming to `Item` is a user message, show this input textfield. I checked this with the `id`'s in the `if` states in the lazycolumn in FirstScreen, you can understand if you look at the FirstScreen. And when the user enters a value in that input textfield, it is added to the same `list` and displayed on the screen, but as messages are added to the `list`, I want the screen to scroll down, as I said above, how can I do this in my code ?

**EDIT**

@GabrieleMariotti

Thanks for your answer, but I guess I didn't explain exactly what I wanted or I didn't understand, sorry. I have a list and messages are added to that list in order, and as they are added, they appear on the screen, so I don't have 100 messages in the list at once. As in a correspondence application, the messages slide down the screen and when it reaches the bottom of the screen, the recently added messages are not visible. What I want is that the user can see the last added message, that is, the screen scrolls to the bottom so that the user can see the last added message. I did the answer you gave but it gave the following error

```
@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function
```

and I couldn't figure out exactly how to use it in my question. If your answer is the last index, it returns true, otherwise it returns false. If this is exactly the answer to my question, I couldn't figure out how and where to use it in my code.Could it be a problem with lazycolumn because lazycolumn is not supposed to do this task automatically? thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

```
listState.isScrolledToEnd() // error occurs Unresolved reference
```

The function `listState.isScrolledToEnd()` currently doesn't exist in Compose.

Starting from `1.4.0-alpha03` you can use **`LazyListState#canScrollForward`** to check if you are at the end of the list.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
val isAtBottom = !listState.canScrollForward
```

Before `1.4.0-alpha03` you have to built a custom function like:

```
@Composable
private fun LazyListState.isAtBottom(): Boolean {

    return remember(this) {
        derivedStateOf {
            val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
            if (layoutInfo.totalItemsCount == 0) {
                false
            } else {
                val lastVisibleItem = visibleItemsInfo.last()
                val viewportHeight = layoutInfo.viewportEndOffset + layoutInfo.viewportStartOffset

                (lastVisibleItem.index + 1 == layoutInfo.totalItemsCount &&
                        lastVisibleItem.offset + lastVisibleItem.size <= viewportHeight)
            }
        }
    }.value
}
```

Comment: My Compose version 1.1.1 and I added the code below as you said, but where should I call it or how do I use it in lazycolumn ? still the screen doesn't scroll down if it overflows as dialogs are added

Comment: @NewPartizal instead of using `listState.isScrolledToEnd()`, you can use `listState.canScrollForward` (1.4.0) or `listState.isAtBottom` (1.x.x)

Comment: I edited my code and added a few posts, can you take a look at them?

Comment: !listState.canScrollForward is triggered when entering the screen as well as when reaching the bottom. can this be prevented?

Answer (score 0):

Please set your `LayColumn`, You don't need to call scrollToEnd, you add to the list, the latest news will be displayed automatically:

```
LazyColumn(
     reverseLayout = true,
     state = listState,
     modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
     horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
     verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
   // do something....
}
```

Comment: I did it but it didn't work properly . you wrote reverseLayour = true. When I added this line my dialogs start end of the screen. I am trying to do normal chat bot app like WhatsApp for example. My dialogs need to start beginning of the screen as a other normal chat apps

Comment: You need to reverse the list